# Running Tensorboard without CUDA support

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

### Is it possible to run Tensorboard on a machine without CUDA support?

I'm working at a computation center (via ssh) which has two major clusters:

- CPU-Cluster which is a general workhorse without CUDA support (no dedicated GPU)
- GPU-Cluster with dedicated GPUs e.g. for running neural networks with tensorflow-gpu.

---

The access to the GPU-cluster is limited to Training etc. such that I can't afford to run Tensorboard on a machine with CUDA-support. Instead, I'd like to run Tensorboard on the CPU-Cluster.
With the TF bundled Tensorboard I get import errors due to missing CUDA support.

---

It seems reasonable that the official Tensorboard should have a mode for running with CPU-only. Is this true?

I've also found an inofficial standalone Tensorboard version ([github.com/dmlc/tensorboard](https://github.com/dmlc/tensorboard)), does this work without CUDA-support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem: just install `tensorflow` instead of `tensorflow-gpu`.

Didn't work for me for a while due to my virtual environment (conda), which didn't properly remove `tensorflow-gpu`.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorboard is not limited by whether a machine has GPU or not.

And as far as I know, what Tensorboard do is parsing events pb files and display them on web. There is not computing, so it doesn't need GPU.

Comment: However, if I execute TB on a CPU-only node, an error is thrown due to missing CUDA support  (https://pastebin.com/tW9yP5B7). It works on a GPU node though!
I guess this is related to the fact that I only have tensorflow-gpu installed. However I'm not sure if I can install the CPU and the GPU version of TF at the same time.